# What's the best way to translate a website

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a website in Django using MySQL, and I have more than 4.000 entries that I want to translate.

What's the best way to do it? Create a new database for every language? Create other table for every language? Or create more entries?

I want 6 or 8 languages so I thought it might be bad to have a table with many records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `TRANSLATIONS` table, that looks something like:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSLATIONS 
(
  translation_id    INTEGER,
  language_id       INTEGER,
  translation       VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (translation_id, language_id)
);
```

Then edit your current schema and/or code to reference the `TRANSLATIONS` table, rather than any hard-coded values (using `translation_id`,`language_id` to lookup). For example, rather than having a `VARCHAR` column in a table, you'd instead have a `NUMBER` column that would "link" to the `TRANSLATIONS` table.

Probably also best to have a `LANGUAGES` table that lists what each `language_id` represents.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE LANGUAGES
(
  language_id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  iso_code      CHAR(4), -- eg "en"
  language_name VARCHAR(32) -- eg "English"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer relies on what kind of data you store and how. I would never suggest making separate database. Depending on the data you can either:

- Create separate rows in same tables and add "language" column to specify which language the content is in.
- Create separate table per langauge to completely separate content.

Which way to go depends on your data, the way you plan to perform queries etc. and is too broad question to answer. You will likely have to apply different method for different tables.

Comment: It's a table of activities. I only want to translate the title and description